# Is it possible to use selenium click outside web browser?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I searched a lot for how to click with selenium outside of web browser (like Desktop applications, for example WhatsApp or Telegram), but I didn't find a way.

This is what clicks only on browser:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value='//span').click()
```

I know other packages like `pyautogui`, but I need to use headless clicking, so up to this moment I think `selenium` solves my problem.

Is it possible to do so with `selenium`? Or are there any other ways to click headless?

**Update 1**

This is my code:

```
from time import sleep
import autoit

n = 0
x = 47
y = 128
sleep(3)
while True:
    n += 1
    sleep(1)
    autoit.control_click(x, y)
    print('Done')
    # x=47, y=128
    if n == 10:
        break
```

And the error when I run:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Saeed\Desktop\python-projects\test.py", line 12, in <module>
    autoit.control_click(x, y)
  File "C:\Users\Saeed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\autoit\autoit.py", line 73, in wrapper
    ret = fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Saeed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\autoit\control.py", line 30, in control_click
    ret = AUTO_IT.AU3_ControlClick(LPCWSTR(title), LPCWSTR(text),
OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x000000000000002F
```

Comment: Have you looked at "PyAutoIt" module ? It has a `control_click` method. Is that what you are looking for ?

Comment: There's winappdriver for windows apps here: https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver

Comment: @S.B I updated the question, and I get that error. I did search but other answers in SO are usually for byte strings, while I do not have any of this kind.

Comment: @pcalkins thanks, I'm seeing it but I did not understand well how to use this until now.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the answer is: **No, you can't**.
Selenium doesn't support clicking or any other iterations with elements out of the Web browser.